# jQuery trouble with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a problem i want to build a ajax one page but i have 2 different js files because when i have my code in 1 file its not working.

how can i combine these js that it doesn't trouble in one .js file

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.visible = function(partial) {

      var $t            = $(this),
          $w            = $(window),
          viewTop       = $w.scrollTop(),
          viewBottom    = viewTop + $w.height(),
          _top          = $t.offset().top,
          _bottom       = _top + $t.height(),
          compareTop    = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
          compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;

        return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));

    };

})(jQuery);

var win = $(window);
var allMods = $(".module");

// Already visible modules
allMods.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
        el.addClass("already-visible"); 
    } 
});

win.scroll(function(event) {

    allMods.each(function(i, el) {
        var el = $(el);
        if (el.visible(true)) {
            el.addClass("come-in"); 
        }
    });

});
```

with this one wich is specified for another page

```
var win = $(window);
var allMods = $(".var");

// Already visible modules
allMods.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
        el.addClass("already-visible"); 
    } 
});

win.scroll(function(event) {

    allMods.each(function(i, el) {
        var el = $(el);
        if (el.visible(true)) {
            el.addClass("come-in-var"); 
        } 
    });
});
```

how can i combine it? Thanks!

Comment: What error do you get when you combine them?

Comment: the two animations are not working :( one the first works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `allMods` is causing the issue. Since it points to two different selectors. Try below code.

Based on the class either `module`/`var` addClass `come-in`/`come-in-var`.

```
var allMods = $(".module, .var");
win.scroll(function(event) {
    allMods.each(function(i, el) {
        var el = $(el);
        if (el.visible(true)) {
            el.addClass(el.hasClass('module') ? "come-in" : "come-in-var"); 
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: var win = $(window); oh i deleted this line... thank you so much its working!

Answer (score 0):

`allMods` variable is conflicting with first file. Try adding scope to your second file ( In your first file as well you have scoped but not the complete file ); Scoping will change the scope of your variables and `allMods` will no more conflict.

```
( function($) {  // Scoped
var win = $(window);
var allMods = $(".var");

// Already visible modules
allMods.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
        el.addClass("already-visible"); 
    } 
});

win.scroll(function(event) {

    allMods.each(function(i, el) {
        var el = $(el);
        if (el.visible(true)) {
            el.addClass("come-in-var"); 
        } 
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```